# Trichedit to Rave memo buffer

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

How do I put formatted content of a `TRichEdit` into a Rave memo buffer, `TMemoBuf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the [`Lines.SaveToStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.Lines) function from the [`TRichEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TRichEdit) component to get the Formated text (rtf) and the use the [`TMemoBuf.RTFLoadFromStream`](http://www.chmlib.com/RaveDevRef/rtfloadfromstream.htm) function to load the rtf text into the `TMemoBuf`.

```
var
  MemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MemoryStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    //get the rtf data from the RichEdit into from the Memory stream
    RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToStream(MemoryStream);
    MemoryStream.Position := 0;
    //load the rtf data into the TMemoBuf
    MemoBuf1.RTFLoadFromStream(MemoryStream,0);
  finally
    MemoryStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```